# Customizing richtextbox from formfield

Tags: javascript, ribbon, list-form, html-editor, richhtmlfield

This applies to SharePoint 2010.

I have a requirement where users can only use a very specific set of "styles" when creating their content for SharePoint lists. As the "styles" ribbon button does not seem to work for formfields renders in list forms (new, edit, disp), I would have to remove each and every font style individually to be able to use the built in WYSIWYG editor. However, the htmleditorstyles.css file I need to modify for being able to do this is a core SharePoint file that might be overwritten in updates, and would have to be concurrently updated across a server farm through a feature deployment by the administrator.

Now I'm wondering, is this information correct? Am I missing anything? Because it seems using something like TinyMCE + Custom field type would be a better solution for doing this.

Many thanks

Comment: Yes, pretty rude of me. Sometime I just get too absorbed :). Thanks for the heads up.